# Reading right ascension/declination coordinates in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a two column file with right ascension/declination coordinates:

```
18:42:21.8 -23:04:52
20:55:00.8 -17:23:19
```

I can read the first column specifying data as 'timefmt' but it seems there is no way to do a similar reading for angular data. I could, of course delete :'s and plot ($2+$3/60+$3/3600) but I wonder if there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function which is doing the job for you, which might be a bit more convenient and shorter in the plot command.

- Convert your hours, minutes, seconds or degrees, minutes, seconds into seconds via `strptime()` or `timecolumn()`. In gnuplot console type check `help strptime`, `help timecolumn` and `help time_specifiers`. Use `%tH:%tM:%tS`, not `%H:%M:%S`.

**However**, you have to be careful how [gnuplot interprets negative times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60995400/7295599):

if your input time is for example `-00:17:56.7` gnuplot will interpret this as `+00:17:56.7` which is not what you expect. Apparently, `-00` is equal to `+00` and hence `17` is interpreted as positive, although you intended it to be negative. A workaround in this special case would be the following:

Create a function `myTimeSign(s)` which checks if hours are `0` and if the first character of your time is `-` and will return `-1`, and `1` otherwise.

```
myTimeSign(s) = strptime("%tH",s)==0 && s[1:1] eq '-' ? -1 : 1
```

Multiply this with your time. This will do here as workaround, but not in general.

**Update:**
This has been reported as bug (https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2245/) and is already fixed in the development version of gnuplot.

**Code:**

```
### time / angle conversion
reset session
set size square
set object 1 rect from graph 0,0 to graph 1,1 fc rgb "black"

$Orion <<EOD
05:55:10.29   +07:24:25.3   0.42   Betelgeuse
05:14:32.27   -08:12:05.9   0.18   Rigel
05:25:07.87   +06:20:59.0   1.64   Bellatrix
05:32:00.40   -00:17:56.7   2.20   Mintaka
05:36:12.81   -01:12:06.9   1.69   Alnilam
05:40:45.52   -01:56:33.3   1.88   Alnitak
05:47:45.39   -09:40:10.6   2.07   Saiph
05:35:08.28   +09:56:03.0   3.47   Meissa
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%tH:%tM:%tS"

RA(n) = timecolumn(n,myTimeFmt)
myTimeSign(s) = strptime("%tH",s)==0 && s[1:1] eq '-' ? -1 : 1   # returns -1 if hours are -00
Dec(n) = timecolumn(n,myTimeFmt)*myTimeSign(strcol(n))

set xrange[strptime(myTimeFmt,"06:12"):strptime(myTimeFmt,"05:00")] reverse
set format x "%H^h%M^m" time
set yrange[strptime(myTimeFmt,"-12:00"):strptime(myTimeFmt,"+12:00")]
set format y "%tH°%tM'" time
set tics out

plot $Orion u (RA(1)):(Dec(2)):(-log10($3)+1.5) w p pt 7 ps var lc rgb "yellow" notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Kinda strange. The help on 'strptime' says it "converts it into seconds since the year 1970" which is not true. It simply converts it to seconds...

Comment: the problem is the `-00:17:56`. gnuplot ignores the `-` because `-0` is `0`, and then counts the `17` as positive.

Comment: `strptime()` works fine. e.g. 01:00:00 corresponds to January 1st 1970 01:00:00, which is 3600 seconds past beginning of 1970.

Comment: Hah! True, there is no date, so it is all Jan 1st... :-)

Comment: By the way, one has to remove '15' in RA... It changes in hours from 0 to 23.59:59...

Comment: I revised the code and included a workaround for the `-00` hours issue.

Comment: Yeah... This s[1:1] eq '-' ? -1 : 1 is what did not know possible in Gnuplot... Although I wish there was a more straight approach to the task. Thanks.

Comment: So, problem solved, answer acceptable? also check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61005915/7295599 Yes, well, I hope that the gnuplot developers will somehow implement this or something similar in the next version.

Comment: I would say `timecolumn(n,myTimeFmt)` is pretty straight, if there wasn't this `-00`-bug. I placed a bug report at https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2245/ . And I've just seen that you wrote on gnuplot mailing list. Let's see what will happen.

Comment: Yeah... I see that it is already fixed in the developers tree...